# How can I set a background to 100% width while having the text within it at another width?

Tags: html, css, width

I'm starting out with CSS, so I'm afraid to edit the code I already have. Part of it is main { max-width: 60em } for the text to be centered and a sticky menu. When I try adding .container { width: 100% } to another section like body or div, it messes up my sticky menu.

How can I make just one part of the page have a full width background?

(The issue is not about centering the look of the text, but the positioning on a page.) I want the text to be within 960px while having the background at 100% width.

```css
/* === Globals === */
html,body,div,header,footer,section,article,figure,nav,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,font,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td{background:transparent;border:0;font-size:100%;margin:0;outline:0;padding:0;vertical-align:baseline;}body{line-height:1;}ol,ul{list-style:none;}blockquote,q{quotes:none;}/*remembertodefinefocusstyles!*/:focus{outline:0;}/*remembertohighlightinsertssomehow!*/ins{text-decoration:none;}del{text-decoration:line-through;}/*tablesstillneed'cellspacing="0"'inthemarkup*/table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}


/* === Structure === */
.clear  {
 clear: both;
}

#footer  {
 background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 1.0);
 bottom: 0;
 color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 1.0);
 height: 350px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
}

 #footer  p {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
 }
  
  #footer  p:first-child  {
   padding-top: 75px;
  }

.menu {
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0.5em 0 #000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0.5em 0 #000;
 box-shadow: 0 0 0.5em 0 #000;

 background-color: rgba(170, 68, 100, 0.95);
 clear: both;
 display: block;
 height: 40px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 10px 0;
 position: fixed;
 text-align: center;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 99;
}

 .menu ul li a,
 .menu-trigger {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 50px;
 }
 
  .menu ul li a:active {
   color: #ffffff;
  }

  .menu ul li a:hover  {
   color: #aa4464;
   background: #fff;
  }
 
   .menu ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
   }
 
 .menu ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 160px;
 }
 
  .menu  ul  ul  li  {
   display: block;
  }
  
   .menu  ul  ul  li  a  {
    background-color: rgba(170, 68, 100, 0.95);
    color: white;
    display: block;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100px;
   }
   
 .menu-trigger {
  display: none;
 }
 
main {
 margin: auto;
 max-width: 60em;
 padding: 75px 5% 50px;
}

main  h2 {
 font-family: 'Exo', serif;
 font-size: 36px;
 font-weight: 600;
 line-height: 150%;
}

main  p  {
 font-family: 'Arial', 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 150%;
}

.container {
 width: auto 100%;
}

.testimonial {
 margin: auto;
 max-width: 60em;
 padding: 75px 5% 50px;
 color: #fff;
}

.work ul {
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 max-width: 60em;
}

.work li {
 float: left;
 margin: 1em 1%;
 padding: 1em 1%;
 text-align: center;
 width: 20%;
}
 
.work a {
 color: #fff;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 text-decoration: none;
}
  
.work h3 {
 color: #666666;
 font-family: Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 left: 0;
 margin-top: -8px;
 position: absolute;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 top: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
  
.work img {
 width: 100%;
}

/* 960 */
@media all and (min-width: 960px) {
 main  h1  {
  font-size: 160px;
 }
}

/* 600 */
@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
 main  h2  {
  font-size: 36px;
 }
 main  p  {
  font-size: 20px;
 }
 main  h1  {
  font-size: 96px;
 }
}

/* 768 */
@media only screen and 
(max-width: 768px){
 .menu-trigger {
  display: none;
 }
 
 .work li {
  width: 45%;
 }
}

/* 480 */
@media only screen and 
(max-width: 480px){
 .menu-trigger {
  display: inline;
  position: fixed;
 }
 
 .menu  ul  li  a  {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 96;
 }

 .menu ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 160px;
 }
 
  .menu  ul  ul  li  {
   display: block;
  }

 ul.open  {
  background-color: rgba(170, 68, 100, 0.95);
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 60px;
  width: 100%;
 }
 
 .work li {
  padding: inherit;
  width: 95%;
 }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1" />
 <title>Tantalizea Lacaden</title>
        
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="parallax-styles.css" />
 <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo:400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>

 <nav class="menu open">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Work</a>
             <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Illustrations</a></li>
                    <li><a href="photography.html">Photography</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Printed Work</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>

  </ul>
  <a href="#" class="menu-trigger"><img src="hamburger.png" width="20px" /></a>
 </nav>

 <main>
        
  <img src="http://placehold.it/960x500">
  
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean fringilla, purus in porttitor pellentesque, erat arcu tincidunt diam, dapibus faucibus leo mauris at sapien. In porttitor vehicula sodales. Vivamus massa neque, facilisis eu felis ut, aliquet convallis nisi. Nam elementum tellus vitae gravida fermentum. Nullam et imperdiet leo. Integer ut euismod lorem, in placerat lacus. Curabitur bibendum arcu ut feugiat commodo. Suspendisse ut mi vel orci ullamcorper tincidunt. Nam vitae fringilla nibh. Nullam hendrerit blandit velit eu hendrerit.</p><br />
  <p>Praesent eu enim non massa pellentesque lobortis. In in sagittis dolor. Aliquam non massa erat. Ut aliquet gravida tellus, sed volutpat nibh condimentum et. Nunc quam purus, vehicula quis venenatis et, porttitor vel dolor. Cras facilisis dui id elit bibendum, in ullamcorper leo ultricies. Praesent rutrum lacus sit amet sem convallis, ut interdum dolor vestibulum</p><br />
  <p>Tum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In iaculis pharetra odio, sit amet consectetur elit facilisis ac. Praesent eget tristique ipsum. Donec malesuada bibendum lacinia. Praesent non purus sodales, pulvinar mi vitae, tincidunt leo. Phasellus vitae elit ut nisl semper fringilla id rutrum dolor. Donec a massa adipiscing, cursus risus vitae, porttitor tortor. Nullam sagittis est sapien, sit amet pharetra turpis imperdiet vel. Etiam sit amet ligula pretium, vulputate eros ac, bibendum velit. Aenean convallis ante purus, ac bibendum orci laoreet ac. Donec a convallis mauris. Nulla non lacus non ipsum pretium tempor. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean at ipsum vulputate, sagittis dui ut, pharetra neque. Nam eget sodales orci. Aliquam pharetra nunc at nisl pellentesque, nec fringilla enim iaculis.</p><br />
 
 <section class="work">
  <ul align="middle">
   <li>
    <a href="illustration.html">
     <h3>Illustration</h3>
     <img src="images/illustration.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="photography.html">
     <h3>Photography</h3>
     <img src="images/photography.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="print.html">
     <h3>Print</h3>
     <img src="images/print.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="web.html">
     <h3>Web</h3>
     <img src="images/web.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="clear"></div>
 </section>
 </main>
 
   <div class="container"><div class="testimonial"><h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean fringilla, purus in porttitor pellentesque, erat arcu tincidunt diam, dapibus faucibus leo mauris at sapien. In porttitor vehicula sodales. Vivamus massa neque, facilisis eu felis ut, aliquet convallis nisi. Nam elementum tellus vitae gravida fermentum. Nullam et imperdiet leo. Integer ut euismod lorem, in placerat lacus. Curabitur bibendum arcu ut feugiat commodo. Suspendisse ut mi vel orci ullamcorper tincidunt. Nam vitae fringilla nibh. Nullam hendrerit blandit velit eu hendrerit.</p><br /></div></div>



<footer id="footer">
  <p>tantalizea@gmail.com</p>
  <p>2015 © Tantalizea Lacaden. All Rights Reserved.</p>
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Setting `max-width` for centering doesn't seem right. Have you tried other ways to center it?(Read: `text-align: center`)

Comment: Yes, but I'm not trying to fix how the text looks. The problem is  making it stay within 960px and have the background width 100%.

Comment: Where is your sticky menu? Can we have all the codes?

Comment: Full HTML and CSS for the page are updated.

Answer (score 0):

I tried different things with the width, so I thought of doing the opposite. The following code worked! Thanks for the help, everyone! :)

```html
.container {
 min-width: 100%;
 background-color: #aa4464;
}
```